# Is it possible to console.log a GET request in in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to test the results of my crud operations for a node.js/express app on the console but it doesn't seem to work for `GET` only for POST.

I have this function:

```
   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('cars').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.log(results)
    })
   })
```

But I am unable to find a way to execute and retrieve the results in the console. How can I do this?

Comment: you are doing right try to print comment with results: console.log("result is",results);

Comment: Nothing happens. Terminal remains silent unless I POST.` nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
listening on 3000`

Comment: In a node.js callback style coding always check for error and handle it. Here something is wrong with the MongoDB call. Try to console.log(err);

Comment: Just check if your get request is reaching inside get . Do console.log before  db.collection

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
db.open(function(err,db){ // <------everything wrapped inside this function
         db.collection('cars', function(err, collection) {
             collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
                 console.log(results);
             });
         });
     });
```

Comment: thanks for the answers but none work so far. Isn't there a way to execute get from the console in order to force the results? At the moment I am not seeing what would make it work unlike a POST request because it involves some kind of submission.

Comment: I can get it to render onto a page but not in the console: `res.render('index.ejs', {quotes: result})`

Answer (score 0):

that looks like MongoDB to me, and if it is, then I don't think [the cursor.toArray() method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) takes a callback function at all.  Instead it iterates over all results and exhausts the cursor for you.

try `console.log(db.collection('cars').find().toArray());`.

Comment: the callback is inside the `toArray()` call, not the `find()` call.